# Using PHP Sockets as a "Relay"

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to create a left > php socket-server < right relation with php sockets.

Let's say that I have a server-daemon on the left side, like a vnc-server that connects to the socket-server.

On the right side I've got a client that want to connect to the left server-daemon, but it has to be done through the socket-server.

The server environment is a fully featured Linux or Mac OS X Server host with php5.3.

Any idéas?

Thanks
/ Trikks

Comment: ...and php really is your only option? A long running daemon is not the sweet spot for php.

Comment: No, i can use pretty much any service

Comment: Oh, btw. This wouldn't be a "long running" daemon. The plan is to fire it up through a admin interface when needed! :)

Comment: You could also fire it from inetd.

Comment: You can install/configure a proxy or tunnel server. But that belongs on http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up building a solution in objective-c running as a daemon instead.